# Unable to access validation errors using bootstrap_forms gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for, bootstrap-sass

Unable to display validation errors using the gem 'bootstrap_forms', '~> 2.0.0' (http://github.com/potenza/bootstrap_form).

**models/client.rb**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

**views/clients/new.html.haml**

```
= bootstrap_form_for @client do |f|
  = f.object.errors.messages
  %h1 Create New Client
  .row-fluid
    .span3= f.text_field :name, :class => 'span50'
  = f.submit
```

When submitting the above form code, f.object.class is 'Client', and f.object.messages is an empty hash.

Switching  this code to use rails built in form builder allows me to see the validation errors:

**views/clients/new.html.haml**

```
= form_for @client do |f|
  = f.object.errors.messages
  %h1 Create New Client
  .row-fluid
    .span3= f.text_field :name, :class => 'span50'
  = f.submit
```

Using this, f.object.messages is {:name=>["can't be blank"]}.

Does this make any sense?  I cannot understand why f.object.errors.messages is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  f.errors.full_messages
```

Comment: Using `f.errors.full_messages`, I am receiving: 

undefined method `errors'

Comment: No sorry, it was giving me that error.  However, `@client.errors.full_messages` is giving me an empty array (only when using bootstrap_form_for).

Comment: did you try adding this line as in the doc `<%= f.alert_message "Please fix the errors below." %>` ???

Comment: Well now I feel foolish, thanks to your comment I have now realized I was using `gem 'bootstrap_forms'` and **not** `gem 'bootstrap_form'` which is what I originally linked above.

I have actually been using https://github.com/sethvargo/bootstrap_forms. 

However, when switching gems to the one originally linked, I am now able to access the validation messages in `f.object.full_messages`.  In-line errors are working to boot.

No idea what the problem was with the other gem.  Thanks a ton for helping me realize my mistake @codeit! I'll stick with this as it's working!